# Can't see mouse pointer in Linux VM

Tags: virtual-machines, rhel5, vmware-workstation

I have installed vmware workstation 7 on  windows 7 on my thinkpad laptop.

I have installed RHEL 5 inside virtual machine.

The problem is i can't see any mouse pointer inside that machine.

I see one more mouse pointer but it looks like that moves with mouse but when i click then its don;'t work.

If i right click then then menu opens some where else on screen

it looks like real mouse pointer is hidden but works

I have reinsalled vmware tools but same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [VMWare Tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=340) in the guest operating system.

Comment: i have installed the vmware tools as well but still mouse didn't show up

Comment: Did you try running xinit?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with CentOS in Oracle Virtual Box and I solved it changing the configuration of "Pointing device" as show in the picture.

[image: Image of same configuration in Oracle VirtualBox]

See if there is any configuration like that in VMWare.
Also I found this possible fix if your host machine is Windows:

```
To resolve this issue, ensure that the mouse driver is the VMware Pointing Device driver:
    Log in to the virtual machine.
    Right-click My Computer and click Manage.
    Select Device Manager and expand Mice and other pointing devices.
    The VMware driver is named VMware Pointing Device. If another driver is present, update the driver:
        Right-click the mouse driver and click Update Driver Software.
        Browse to the C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\Drivers\mouse and click Next.
        Select VMware Pointing Device and click Next. 

Note: The operating system may need to be rebooted for the change to take effect.
```

Source: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2012606